# Type <String^> in list or vector in C++/CLI (CLR Console Application)

Tags: .net, c++-cli

About to use a stl::list (or std::vector, previously), I got stuck with this error message:

**error C3699: '&&' : cannot use this indirection on type 'System::String ^'**

Since I am not very experienced with C++/CLI classes interoperability, this error message keeps flashing whenever I declare a std::list or use push_back or emplace_back on it. What is wrong, and how do I use it? Currently, I am studying a book on CLR applications (Microsoft Visual C++/CLI by Julian Templeman)
Thank you for your help in advance. Code snippet:

```
void Printout()
{
    String^ strcat(" ");
    String^ path("./somefile.txt");
    FileStream^ inf = gcnew FileStream(path, FileMode::Open, FileAccess::Read);
    list<String^> vect; // = gcnew list<String^>();
    list<String^>::iterator vectit;
    stringstream strst;
    while (strcat != "")
    {
        StreamReader^ sr = gcnew StreamReader(inf, Encoding::UTF8);
        String^ content = sr->ReadToEnd();
        Console::WriteLine(content);
        strcat += content;
        int preQomma = strcat->IndexOf(",");
        //int postQomma = strcat->IndexOf(",", preQomma + 1);
        //Console::WriteLine(strcat->Remove(preQomma, preQomma + 1));
        vect.push_back(strcat->Remove(preQomma, preQomma+1)); //bummer
        strcat = "";
    }
    strcat = "";
    for (vectit = vect.begin(); vectit != vect.end(); ++vectit)
    {
        strcat = strcat + " " + *vectit;
    }
    Console::WriteLine(strcat);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unmanaged class can't contain managed objects, at least not without jumping through hoops that you probably don't want to deal with.

Instead of using `std::list` or `std::vector`, use the managed type [`List<String^>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1). Since `System::Collection::Generic::List` is a managed type, it can contain the managed `String^` objects.

```
List<String^>^ mylist = gcnew List<String^>();

mylist->Add(strcat->Remove(preQomma, preQomma+1)); //bummer removed!
```

---

That said, a standard warning/reminder: C++/CLI is intended for interop, providing a middle layer to allow .Net code to call unmanaged C++. While it's certainly possible, you probably don't want to be writing your main application in C++/CLI. In general, you probably want to write your application in C#, and use C++/CLI for the interop things where P/Invoke isn't sufficient.